# How to retrieve and output the last record by foreign id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have 2 Models in my application. Project & Note. A project has_many notes. This all works great but on the projects index page.html.erb I would like to show the last note for a project.

My question is how do I retrieve this and then display it, on the index screen?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the last note using `project.notes.last`. In your view, add below :

```
<% projects.each do |project| %>
  <% last_note = project.notes.last %>
  <%= last_note.note unless last_note.nil? %> # get last note per project if it exists
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you but <%= project.notes.last %> only outputs <Note:0xb4eed9c8> but not the note.

Comment: @DamonDelcoro You need to define what you want from Notes model, I don't know which field you want to show, i will update my answer with arbitrary field.

Comment: The field is acutely called note.

Comment: @DamonDelcoro check upated answer

Comment: That did It! Wow thank you for your knowledge and fast response. It is very much appreciated. :)

Comment: @DamonDelcoro Thanks, please feel free to mark it as answer.

Comment: I have attempted to mark this as the correct answer, but it says my reputation is not high enough. But Thank you again.

Comment: @DamonDelcoro No worries,  so glad to help you